# how to add a second path to the same namespace in the zend autoloader

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoload, zend-loader

We are working on a new zend framework project and most things are going fine with the bootstrap:

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'List8D',
            'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
        ));

        return $autoloader;
    }

    protected function _initDoctype()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('view');
        $view = $this->getResource('view');
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_TRANSITIONAL');
    }

    protected function _initRegistry()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('db');
        Zend_Registry::set('dbResource', $this->getPluginResource('db'));
    } 


}
```

but we want to add a second path to the List8D Namespace so that if the autoloader can not find it in `dirname(__FILE__)` it looks there

I've look in the documentation and found lots on adding a namespace but nothing on having multiple paths for the same namespace

Answer (score -1):

Specifying basePath as array doesn't work? But I think it doesn't make much of a sense to do this.

Follow mind map:

```
are your classes application specific or global:
  specific
    move both folders to one folder inside application
  global 
    move both folders to one folder inside your include path
  some are specific, some global
    separate them to different namespaces
```

I'm not aware of any situation where you should have same prefixed classes in different folder...